# Python Can't Find Importlib

Tags: python, module

I am trying to import the importlib module but I get this message:

`>>> importlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'importlib' is not defined`

I have manually located the importlib file within the Python folder, so I know I have it. I am running Python version 3.4.1. I also tried to pip install importlib but it wasn't found either.

What's going on?

Comment: You need to `import` the module first, then you can call it

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong line of code. I have been calling **import importlib** but it can't find it

Answer (score 10):

You need to use an [`import`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html) statement to load it in:

```
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib
<module 'importlib' from 'C:\\Python33\\lib\\importlib\\__init__.py'>
```

Comment: Sorry I copied the wrong line of code. I have been calling **import importlib** but it can't find it